# Text not found in .txt , but it's already there

Tags: java, file

I am going through *Mooc.fi* Java course and I can't figure how *not* to write String into file if the file already contains it. I tried only with one String and tried  without " " (empty space), and without another string, but still it adds the string even when the file already contains it.

And `translate()` method doesn't find/return whole line in which it found the given word.

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MindfulDictionary dict = new MindfulDictionary();
        dict.add("apina", "monkey");
        dict.add("banaani", "banana");
        dict.add("apina", "apfe");

        System.out.println( dict.translate("apina") );
        System.out.println( dict.translate("monkey") );
        System.out.println( dict.translate("programming") );
        System.out.println( dict.translate("banana") );

    }
}
```

---

```
public class MindfulDictionary {
    File file;
    FileWriter writer; 
    Scanner imeskanera;
    
    public MindfulDictionary() throws Exception {
        this.file  = new File("C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\test.txt");
        this.imeskanera = new Scanner(this.file, "UTF-8");
        
    }
        
    public void add(String word, String translation) throws Exception {
        boolean found = false;
        while(this.imeskanera.hasNextLine()) {
            String lineFromFile = this.imeskanera.nextLine();
            if(word.contains(lineFromFile)) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found) {
            this.writer = new FileWriter(this.file,true);
            this.writer.write(word +" " + translation +"\n");
            this.writer.close();
        }
    }
    
    public String translate(String word) throws Exception {
        
        String line = null;
        while(this.imeskanera.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = this.imeskanera.nextLine();
            if(data.contains(word)) {
                line = data;
                break;
            }
        
    }
        return line;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include a sample of your file with a few entries in it?

Comment: it is empty file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `Scanner` object has already been consumed by the `add()` method. You need to reopen the input stream in order to read the contents of the file. If you add

```
this.imeskanera = new Scanner(this.file, "UTF-8");
```

At the beginning of the `translate()` method, it should word. Which basically tell you that there is no need for `Scanner` to be a global field. Use it locally in each method. This is how I have explain the concept of file streams in the past:

> ***Think about file streams (for reading and writing) logically. You
> cannot allow for such a stream to be "circular". Otherwise, when you
> try to get the "next line", there will always be a next line and you
> will never be able to stop reading (or writing). The stream is
> consumed when it reach the end, and once that is done, to go back to
> the beginning of the stream, you will need to open a new one; not
> reuse the old one.***

I thought I needed to add this explanation even after the answer was accepted because I know new developer struggle with this concept and it because of that, it is necessary to explain it in detail.

With that said, your `MindfulDictionary` class should look like this:

```
public class MindfulDictionary {
    File file;
    FileWriter writer;
//    Scanner imeskanera;

    public MindfulDictionary() throws Exception {
        this.file = new File("test.txt"); // I changed the path to the file to make it work for me. You can change it back if you want to.
        file.createNewFile();

    }

    public void add(String word, String translation) throws Exception {
        Scanner imeskanera = new Scanner(this.file, "UTF-8");
        boolean found = false;
        while (imeskanera.hasNextLine()) {
            String lineFromFile = imeskanera.nextLine();
            if (word.contains(lineFromFile)) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            this.writer = new FileWriter(this.file, true);
            this.writer.write(word + " " + translation + "\n");
            this.writer.close();
        }
        imeskanera.close();
    }

    public String translate(String word) throws Exception {
        Scanner imeskanera = new Scanner(this.file, "UTF-8");
        String line = null;
        while (imeskanera.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = imeskanera.nextLine();
            if (data.contains(word)) {
                line = data;
                break;
            }

        }
        imeskanera.close();
        return line;
    }
}
```

I ran your code with my modifications and now the output is

```
apina monkey
apina monkey
null
banaani banana
```

Comment: Normally one would argue that variables that are used in multiple methods should be fields. But I agree, the better solution here is to make the scanner a local variable. Where: in the end, the `add` method could simply invoke the `translate` method, and if that returns null, that means "not found". And then you dont need a scanner in the add method at all. Basically the real issue is code duplication, because *iterating* the file is implemented twice.

Comment: @GhostCat my philosophy with regards to variables is simple: limit the scope of them _unless_ there is a legitimately good reason to graduate them to global. I once shocked a coworker when I created a code block in a method simply to reuse a variable name. I told him for that specific block, the name was meaningful and taken by another local variable so I did that to break ambiguation. My commitment to that rule is that deep. LOL

Comment: To clarify the point of streams, you could have a circular stream. But, in this context, just see why this can't be allowed to happen. Once EOF is reached, that's it.

Comment: My point is to rather limit the number of scopes here. The scanner is needed to iterate the file content. Therefore I suggest that *that* logic (about iterating the file) should exist only once, not twice. Code duplication is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Scanner issue mentioned by the answer of  @hfontanez, following changes.

```
if (word.contains(lineFromFile))
```

This checks if the first word contains the line, this is not true. The file contains the first word and translation. so this can be changed to

```
if (lineFromFile.contains(word))
```

as @ghostCat mentioned searching the key(word) can be refactored. Code with these changes.

```
public class MindfulDictionary {
    File file;
    FileWriter writer;
//    Scanner imeskanera;

    public MindfulDictionary() throws Exception {
        this.file = new File("test.txt"); 
        file.createNewFile();

    }

    public void add(String word, String translation) throws Exception {
        
        if (get(word) == null) {
            this.writer = new FileWriter(this.file, true);
            this.writer.write(word + " " + translation + "\n");
            System.out.println("Out>>:"+word + " " + translation + "\n");
            this.writer.close();
        }
    }
    private String get(String word) throws Exception {
        Scanner imeskanera = new Scanner(this.file, "UTF-8");
        boolean found = false;
        String retStr= null;
        while (imeskanera.hasNextLine()) {
            String lineFromFile = imeskanera.nextLine();
            if (lineFromFile.contains(word)) {
                found = true;
                retStr=lineFromFile;
                break;
            }
        }
        imeskanera.close();
        return(retStr);
    }

    public String translate(String word) throws Exception {
        return get(word);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MindfulDictionary dict = new MindfulDictionary();
        dict.add("apina", "monkey");
        dict.add("apina", "monkey");
        dict.add("banaani", "banana");
        dict.add("apina", "apfe");

        System.out.println( dict.translate("apina") );
        System.out.println( dict.translate("monkey") );
        System.out.println( dict.translate("programming") );
        System.out.println( dict.translate("banana") );

    }

}
```